# Android - LogCat gives a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android-networking

I've tried to create a program which allows users to send an HTTP POST to a PHP script using the following code. I get a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when I click on the send button. (btnSend).

```
package com.naveed.post;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating HTTP client
        final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_post/test.php");
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

                String msg = message.getText().toString();

                   // Building post parameters
                // key and value pair
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));

                // Url Encoding the POST parameters
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Making HTTP Request
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // writing response to log
                    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I know I have to use AsyncTask, so i tried. But I know I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions. My code is below:

```
package com.naveed.post;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                 EditText message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

                    String msg = message.getText().toString();

                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));


            }
        });

    }

   class doThePost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... nameValuePair) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvPairs = nameValuePair[0];
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // Creating HTTP Post
             HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android_post/test.php");
                // Url Encoding the POST parameters
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Making HTTP Request
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // writing response to log
                    Log.d("hello", "done");
                    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                Log.d("hello", "done");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }




        }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Like where you get the exception etc.

Comment: basically when i click the send button, the app closes and i get the follwing message on logcat:
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception

Then I get the exception.

Comment: I know I have to use AsyncTask, so i tried. But I know I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your doInBackground method's code to **protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)** method and it will work. And you have to use the AsyncTask class. Here's the link to the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. It also has how to use sample code.

Comment: did what you said. how should i execute the http request now? i tried creating an instance of the class this way:
    doThePost post = (doThePost) new doThePost().execute();

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Android killing processes which have been running for 5 seconds +.
You have to use AsyncTask.

Comment: I have read that I need AsyncTask to do this, but call me a beginner, I dont know how I would use AsyncTask here.

Comment: I know I have to use AsyncTask, so i tried. But I know I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions.